# Brick not exporting Next or continue

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, state-monad, haskell-brick

I am attempting to build a CLI interface for a basic app using Haskell and the Brick package. In all examples I have seen (including the documentation), the `handleEvent` function has the following type signature, in order to tell Brick to continue or stop execution after the state is updated:

```
AppState -> BrickEvent n e -> EventM n (Next AppState)
```

However, for me, my compiler is saying that `Next` is not found (nor can I manually export it from the package it is meant to be in, `Brick.Main`). The same is true for the `continue` function used below.

Minimum reproducible problem:

Main.hs:

```
module Main where

import Brick.Main
import Brick.Types
import Graphics.Vty.Input.Events

data AppState = AppState deriving (Show, Eq)

handleEvent :: AppState -> BrickEvent n e -> EventM n (Next AppState)
handleEvent s e =
    case e of
        VtyEvent vtye ->
            case vtye of
                EvKey (KChar 'q') [] -> halt s
                _ -> continue s
        _ -> continue s
```

brick-test.cabal:

```
cabal-version:      2.4
name:               brick-test
version:            0.1.0.0

author:             AlexScriba
maintainer:         61542302+AlexScriba@users.noreply.github.com

extra-source-files: CHANGELOG.md

executable brick-test
    main-is:          Main.hs
    build-depends:    
      base ^>=4.14.3.0,
      brick >= 1.7,
      vty
    hs-source-dirs:   app
    default-language: Haskell2010
```

I have tried again in different projects and it seems not to work in any of them. Have also tried with different versions of brick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on answers useful answers, the problem was that the approach above is based on outdated documentation. The latest versions use `MonadState` to handle the state, recommending changing the state using `lens` package.

The changed code (using microlens):

```
import Brick.Main
...

import Lens.Micro.Mtl (use, (.=))
import Lens.Micro.TH (makeLenses)

data AppState = AppState { _example :: String }
makeLenses ''AppState    -- Make lens to 'example'

handleEvent :: BrickEvent n e -> EventM n AppState ()
handleEvent e = do
    eg <- use example    -- Use lens to get _example from state
    example .= "New String"    -- Set example field in state
    
    case e of
        VtyEvent vtye ->
            case stye of
                EvKey (KChar 'q') [] -> halt
                _other -> return ()
        _other -> return ()
```

Answer (score 6):

You're looking at outdated documentation and examples. Look at the ones from the version of `brick` you're using instead. `Next` and `continue` were [removed from `brick` in version 1.0](https://github.com/jtdaugherty/brick/blob/b98acee550cef69e7d1fbb194dc569f385689aca/CHANGELOG.md#10). You now need a type like this for `handleEvent` instead: `BrickEvent n e -> EventM n AppState ()`. And instead of `continue s`, you do `return ()` now.

Comment: Thanks that seems to be correct. Given it is now returning () how do I pass changed state?

Comment: @AlexScriba Can you edit your question to include the way you were trying to do so before?

Comment: @AlexScriba `EventM n AppState` is an instance of `MonadState AppState`, so you just use the usual mtl stuff, e.g. `modify` or `state`, or of course the `lens` combinators for doing monadic updates.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I am not sure what you mean by "trying to do it before", could you elaborate?

Comment: @AlexScriba What did your code to pass changed state look like when you wrote it against the old version of `brick`? Can you edit it into your question? Then I can give you the exact translation of it.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica that is actually amazing! However this is my first time building a brick application, so there is no older version. I believe I have figured out ```lens``` and ```MonadState``` to handle state changes on the new design. I will add it to the original question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For brick-1.4, one of the easiest ways to use event handlers is by modifying the current state into a new state can be achieved by using `get` (just like what you'd do in previous versions). For example, if you have a string field and you want to edit the string, you can achieve it by the following code. Basically here, you can create a text box using this technique -

```
handleEvent :: BrickEvent n e -> EventM n AppState ()
handleEvent e = do
    state <- get -- The current state
    let currentExample = _example state

    case e of
        VtyEvent (EvKey (KChar 'q') [MCtrl]) -> halt
        VtyEvent (EvKey (KChar c) []) ->
            modify (\s -> AppState (currentExample ++ c)) -- append characters that are pressed
        _other -> return ()
```